# php regexp: Find form with hidden input & add another input

Tags: php, html, regex, forms

i need help with this problem:

I have a HTML string with output HTML code and i need search all forms where is specific input (hidden with given name and value). After this hidden input i need add another input with given params (only value is dynamically).

Thanks for replies!

// Sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this;

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('form.html');

if (preg_match('/\<.+? name="other" .+?\>/', $html, $match)) {
    $element = $match[0];
    $element .= '<input type="hidden" name="appended" value="etry">';
    $html = str_replace($match[0], $element, $html);
}

echo $html;
```

In this example it will look for a element that starts with '<' and contains 'name="other"', and ends with '>'. Then it uses this to replace itself in the original document, and append itself again, with the additional html.

This is just an example, as it does not check if you have multiple matches etc.